# Reading from binary file C programming

Tags: c, binaryfiles, fread

I need to read binary which contains 3d dots coordinates but first there are 5 lines which are written to file in normal mode, so first I need to skip that part and read the dots. I tried the `fread` but failed. What am i doing wrong

```
VERSION 1
DOTS x y z
DOTCOUNT 10
DATA binary
33ËB3³ÊB33ÊBfæÊBffÊBfæÉBš™ÊBšÊBš™ÉBÍLÊBÍÌÉBÍLÉB
```

Comment: Search for the fourth '\n' char in your file (opened in binary mode).

Comment: `What am i doing wrong` How we will know? Please include [mcve] .

Comment: First, you should show us the code you are using to accomplish that task.

Comment: _" I tried the fread "_: where is your code? Please read this: [ask]

Answer (score 1):

You are actually looking for the data after the first five '\n' characters.

You can read the first 256 bytes of the file, and look for the new lines. if they are there, you start reading your binary data, right after the fifth occurrence. if you did not find five '\n' character, continue reading the next chunk of 256 bytes, and look for the remaining number of '\n' characters. The binary data shall be read after the first five lines were consumed.

That's all

Comment: No need to implent a read buffer when `FILE *` is allready buffered. Just use `fgetc()` to look for the `'/n'`